# Number Format Not Correct in Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<pre>
  <input type='text' value='0' class='number' name='amount1'>
  <input type='text' value='0' class='number' name='amount2'>
  <input type='text' value='0' class='total' name='total'>
</pre>

<script>
var Total=0;
$(".number").focusout(function(){
if(!isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) || parseInt($(this).val())>=0){
Total+=parseInt($(this).val());
$(".total").text(Total);
}
});
</script>
```

1. when i put in text box '100hai' the javascript take 100 is a number.
   And calculating with 100 
   2.When i put in text box asdas100 it is ok for validation.
   What to do with 1. problem

Comment: use `<input type="number">` and `this.valueAsNumber` instead of `$(this).val()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d37yw04v/

Answer (score 0):

change your html to

```
<pre>
  <input type="number" value="0" class="number" name="amount1" min="1">
 <input type="number" value="0" class="number" name="amount2" min="1">
  <input type='text' value='0' class='total' name='total'>
</pre>
```

by setting the min value you can make sure that use wont be able to insert value less then that

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below if it solve your issue:

```
$(".number").keypress((function (e) {
 //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
 if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
 //display error message
    $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
           return false;
   }
  else {
  Total+=parseInt($(this).val());
  $(".total").text(Total); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use parseInt() method. Use Number(/*your variable*/).